# Is there any way in mongoose to access other Schema fields and update those fileds when a "document" is saved into the DB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently working on a Library Management System and I'm using MongoDB as my Database so in there I have 4 schemas

> 1. User 2) Book 3) Review 4) bookIssue (which handles all the book
>    issuing)

I'll mention just my User and Book Issue schemas here coz I only want help regarding these two Schemas,

```
bookIssueHistory: { type: Array, default: null, }
```

Whenever a book is issued via "bookIssue" Schema I want to store that book's "id" in to the "bookIssueHistory" array (mentioned above) which is in my "userSchema", so I've mentioned both of my schemas below:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter your name'],
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter your email'],
    unique: true,
    lowercase: true,
    validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please enter a valid email'],
  },
  photo: String,
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['user', 'admin'],
    default: 'user',
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please enter your password'],
    minlength: 8,
    select: false,
  },
  passwordConfirm: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Re-Enter your password'],
    validate: {
      validator: function (el) {
        return el === this.password;
      },
      message: 'Entered password and confirmed password do not match',
    },
  },
  passwordChangedAt: Date,
  passwordResetToken: String,
  passwordResetExpires: Date,

  noOfBooksIssued: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },

  currentlyIssuedBooks: {
    type: Number,
    max: [3, 'You are only allowed to issue 3 books at a time'],
    default: 0,
  },

  bookIssueHistory: {
    type: Array,
    default: null,
  },

  active: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true,
    select: false,
  },
});
```

my book issue schema looks like this:

```
const bookIssueSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  issuedAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  totalIssues: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0,
  },
  book: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Book',
    required: [true, 'issue must belong to a book.'],
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: [true, 'issue must belong to a user.'],
  },
});
```

Comment: To clarify. When adding a new `bookIssue`, you want to add `bookIssue._id` to `user. bookIssueHistory` where `user._id == bookIssue.user` ? Is it possible to update the bookIssue and change `bookIssue.user` to another user? If so how should it be handled?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I want to store the "book id" itself into the  "user.bookIssueHistory"  not the "bookIssue._id"

Comment: so when a `bookIssue` is created `bookIssue.book` get pushed into `user.bookIssueHistory` ?

Comment: As I've referenced the book schema itself is there any way I can extract the book id when a new book is issued and store it in the "user.bookIssueHistory" array

Comment: "so when a bookIssue is created bookIssue.book get pushed into user.bookIssueHistory ?" yes exactly this I want

Comment: Only when a new `bookIssue` is created, right?  Or is there a situation where `bookIssue.user` can be modified and you would have to modify the user accordingly?

Comment: Yep I want to update only when a bookIssue is created and not in anyother situation

Comment: Some observation: I noticed you defined `bookIssuHistory` as `type: Array`, any reason why you don't explicitly set the type like this `type: [mongoose.Schema.ObjectId]` (array of `ObjectId`s)?

Comment: Yes i can also explicitly set the type like this I've now changed it to type: [mongoose.Schema.ObjectId] there wasn't any hard reason for setting it to an array, thanks I've now modified my field type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mongoose [middleware](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html), in particular the pre-save hook to run some logic before `bookIssue` get inserted into the database.

```
bookIssueSchema.pre('save', function () {
  // you can access the current document to be saved by `this`
  if (this.isNew) { // apply to new bookIssue only
    await this.model('User').findByIdAndUpdate(this.user, {
      $addToSet: { bookIssueHistory: this.book } // use $addToSet to ensure distinct values, otherwise use $push
    })
  }
})
```

**Important:** The pre-save hook will be run only when you use `BookIssue.create()` or `bookIssue.save()` and not when you run `BookIssue.insertMany()`